# How to conditionally display elements of JSP page and maintain the menus depending on user type

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

How to load menu on webpage depending upon usertype.
I want to make website where some `menus` will be shown when user logs in and it will show more menus when user is `admin`.
I want to build this project using `JSP/Servlet`. I have already achieved it partially with the help of `request.set attribute()` in my servlet and creating menus for admin dynamically but the problem comes when I am clicking the home button in user and trying to redirect to the admin's home page(its actually same for both only 2 more links are visible for admin rights, the two options for admin is getting vanished because its created dynamically with the help of request.getattribute().
Its only gets activated when I hit the servlet and since clicking on home only redirect the jsp to the home page so its not visible for me.
Here is my screenshots before and after clicking the home page button where the last two options are created dynamically on checking the 'usertype'.

After login as admin and not clicking home button: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0UDalBYIopb1daaTVSSnJuTkU/view?usp=sharing

After clicking on Home button:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz0UDalBYIopR05PZjFKQXFxWkU/view?usp=sharing

On clicking any link above I want all the menus to be present.
Please someone help me.

Comment: Are you using realms?

Comment: No, Is it possible by using realms?? actually i am beginner in servlet and jsp so I don't have much knowledge about what is realm. Please guide me how to use it.

Comment: A Realm is a "database" of usernames and passwords that identify valid users of a web application (or set of web applications), plus an enumeration of the list of roles associated with each valid user. You can think of roles as similar to groups in Unix-like operating systems, because access to specific web application resources is granted to all users possessing a particular role (rather than enumerating the list of associated usernames). A particular user can have any number of roles associated with their username.